# How to make turtle go somewhere if bumped into or close to another turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, position, distance, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle


player = input('Pick square or arrow: ')
if player == "arrow":
    turtle.shape("arrow")
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.goto(-400, 20)
elif player == "square":
    turtle.shape("square")
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.goto(-400, 20)
else:
    print ('You did not type square or arrow, so you have been given default.')
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.goto(-400, 20)

    
def up():
    turtle.forward(45)
      
def right():
    turtle.right(90)
  
def left():
    turtle.left(90)

def down():
    turtle.backward(45)
   
sc=turtle.Screen()
sc.setup(600, 600)

turtle.onkey(up,'w')
turtle.onkey(right,'d')
turtle.onkey(left,'a')
turtle.onkey(down,'s')
  
turtle.listen()

turtle.penup()

instructions = turtle.Turtle()
instructions.ht()
instructions.pu()
instructions.goto(-600, 200)
instructions.write("Maze Game", font=('Arial', 32, 'normal'))
instructions.goto(-600, 125)
instructions.write("Touch the Green", font=('Arial', 26, 'normal'))
instructions.goto(-580, 100)
instructions.write("And DIE!!!", font=('Arial', 26, 'normal'))
instructions.goto(-620, 50)
instructions.write("Make it Out to Win", font=('Arial', 26, 'normal'))
instructions.goto(-620, -75)
instructions.write("Use w/a/s/d to move", font=('Arial', 26, 'normal'))


#drawing the maze
maze = turtle.Turtle()

maze.ht()
maze.speed(0)
maze.penup()
maze.goto(-310, 300)
maze.pendown()
maze.pensize(40)
maze.color('green')
maze.forward(700)

maze.ht()
maze.speed(0)
maze.penup()
maze.goto(390, 300)
maze.pendown()
maze.right(90)
maze.pensize(40)
maze.color('green')
maze.forward(300)

maze.ht()
maze.speed(0)
maze.penup()
maze.goto(390, 0)
maze.pendown()
maze.left(90)
maze.pensize(40)
maze.color('green')
maze.forward(125)

maze.ht()
maze.speed(0)
maze.penup()
maze.goto(515, 0)
maze.pendown()
maze.right(90)
maze.pensize(40)
maze.color('green')
maze.forward(100)
```

I am making a maze game but I won't it so that when the player hits the maze it gets reset to the starting position but I don't know how.

I've tried one way with a distance method it did not work, but maybe because I did it wrong. I want it so that when the player hits the maze it gets reset to the starting position.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this is a difficult problem when using turtle.  But since you're only using horizontal and vertical lines for your maze (and assuming you continue to do so) we can implement a simple wall collision test.

First, you need to explicitly store your lines in a data structure.  Second, for the simple test to work, all your lines have to be described left to right or top to bottom:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

LINES = [
    ((-310, 300), (390, 300)),
    ((390, 300), (390, 0)),
    ((390, 0), (515, 0)),
    ((515, 100), (515, 0)),
]

WALL_WIDTH = 40
PLAYER_WIDTH = 20
JUST_TOUCHING = WALL_WIDTH/2 + PLAYER_WIDTH/2

LARGE_FONT = ('Arial', 32, 'normal')
MEDIUM_FONT = ('Arial', 26, 'normal')

def up():
    player.forward(PLAYER_WIDTH/2)
    check_collision()

def right():
    player.right(90)
    check_collision()

def left():
    player.left(90)
    check_collision()

def down():
    player.backward(PLAYER_WIDTH/2)
    check_collision()

def check_collision():
    x, y = player.position()

    for ((a, b), (c, d)) in LINES:
        if a == c:  # vertical wall
            if abs(x - a) < JUST_TOUCHING and d - JUST_TOUCHING < y < b + JUST_TOUCHING:
                player.undo()
        elif b == d:  # horizontal wall
            if abs(y - b) < JUST_TOUCHING and a - JUST_TOUCHING < x < c + JUST_TOUCHING:
                player.undo()

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1300, 650)

instructions = Turtle()
instructions.hideturtle()
instructions.penup()
instructions.goto(-600, 200)
instructions.write("Maze Game", font=LARGE_FONT)
instructions.goto(-600, 125)
instructions.write("Touch the Green", font=MEDIUM_FONT)
instructions.goto(-580, 100)
instructions.write("And DIE!!!", font=MEDIUM_FONT)
instructions.goto(-620, 50)
instructions.write("Make it Out to Win", font=MEDIUM_FONT)
instructions.goto(-620, -75)
instructions.write("Use w/a/s/d to move", font=MEDIUM_FONT)

maze = Turtle()
maze.hideturtle()
maze.speed('fastest')
maze.pensize(WALL_WIDTH)
maze.color('green')

for ((a, b), (c, d)) in LINES:
    maze.penup()
    maze.goto(a, b)
    maze.pendown()
    maze.goto(c, d)

player = Turtle()
player.shape("turtle")
player.penup()
player.goto(-400, 20)

screen.onkey(up, 'w')
screen.onkey(right, 'd')
screen.onkey(left, 'a')
screen.onkey(down, 's')

screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

The above only prevents the player from crossing maze lines for testing purposes.  You can change the code to end the game instead.

I needed to make the player's movements smaller as your original step distance is greater than the wall width so the player could "step over" a wall with my simple collision test!

This collision logic is *fragile* (and possibly incorrect in places), so keep your maze simple and spacious!